# Install OpenBSD on Wifi-only laptop?

Tags: firmware, openbsd

I did succeed to mount the firmware in usb, but how to use it ?

I got wifi only Slim laptop , no ethernet and put another TP-Link rtl8188eus wifi still not detected

`pkg_add or fw_update` is not found

I use install69.img on usb drive

Is there's any options to install without internet?

Comment: Have you checked out the [OpenBSD](http://daemonforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=11) or [FreeBSD](https://forums.freebsd.org/) forums?

Comment: I did, even my rhel / centos can't get a drivers

Answer (score 0):

Try the explanations of this post https://dev.to/jmarhee/configuring-wifi-firmware-at-installation-for-openbsd-25pl

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1085980)